# javascript not calculating the correct output for a time subraction

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with a javascript I'm trying to integrate with our monitoring tool. Done quite a lot of searching on this but can't seem to find the answer on where I'm going wrong. Would really apprecaite any help if possible please.

We have a third party .json page URL which updates every 5 minutes and returns a date / time stamp in this format:

"2021-07-06 10:13:58"

We have a javascript which is trying to parse this date / time, check the current time and then subtract the two times. If the current time is greater than 30 seconds since the .json page time, it generates an alert.

I've made a few changes to the script so far, this is my latest version...

```
var responseBody = response.getResponseBody();
var myObj = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var time = myObj.updated;
var amendedTime = time.replace(' ','T');

var respTime = Date.parse(amendedTime);
var curTime = Date.now();
var delta = respTime - curTime;

if (delta > 3000)
{
   api.info("Time has not updated in the last 30 seconds " + delta);
   api.fail("Time has not updated in the last 30 seconds " + delta);
}
```

An example of my last run

- The date / time on the .json page was 2021-07-06 10:13:58
- The script run time was 10:17
- Response / output from the script run was: "Time has not updated in the last 30 seconds 3344037"

The millisecond conversion is 55 minutes which is clearly a lot more than the expected delta, so would have expected to see something like 182000 / 182 seconds.

So not sure why the output is returning a much bigger time difference, and thinking I may be doing something wrong with my var curTime line?

Thank you

Comment: 3000 is 3 seconds. 30,000 is 30 seconds

Comment: why are you doing string manipulation on the date? is the provider not, giving a standard date? `Date.parse` is no longer recommended, and you should be using `try`-`catch` because `JSON.parse` can `throw`

Comment: use `myDate.toISOString()` or `myDate.toUTCString()` to serialize a date and use `new Date(myDateString)` to deserialize it

Comment: Hi Mulan, yes the provider looks to be giving a standard date, but I removed the blank space in between the date and time on the json parse as my script didn't work without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You must take timezones into account. `Date.now()` is tied to UTC timezone and your response is not.

Your math also needs to be revered to:

```js
var delta = curTime - respTime;
```

Given the code you have provided and what you believe to be the times it is using, your delta would be a negative number (That's how you can tell you are working with different timezones).

By the looks of it you may be able to get away with simply adding an hour to the "current time" (see below), but that is definitely not good practice and I greatly urge you not to use it for anything more than testing.

```js
var delta = (curTime + 3_600_000) - respTime;
```

It should also be noted that your conditional is testing against 3 seconds and not 30 seconds, add an extra zero: `30_000`